# Rails Table header row repeating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, html-table

my table header row repeats after each player in my loop. I have tried moving the loop after the column header is built but then I only get one row with the formatting and the rest is just one big pile of data.  Thanks.

This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq1Zi.jpg

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>


<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
 <th class="name">Player</th>
 <th class="stat">pV</th>
 <th class="stat">rV</th>

</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>

 <td class="name"> <%= player.player %> </td>
 <td class="stat"> <%= player.pv %> </td>
 <td class="stat"> <%= player.rv %> </td>

</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm hearing you correctly, this should look like this:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="name">Player</th>
    <th class="stat">pV</th>
    <th class="stat">rV</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <% @players.each do |player| %>
    <tr>
     <td class="name"> <%= player.player %> </td>
     <td class="stat"> <%= player.pv %> </td>
     <td class="stat"> <%= player.rv %> </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @frankburke333 You are welcome. P.s. I want to direct your attention on extra `<% end %>` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your `each` loop around just the `<tr>` tags:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th class="name">Player</th>
       <th class="stat">pV</th>
       <th class="stat">rV</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @players.each do |player| %>
      <tr>
       <td class="name"> <%= player.player %> </td>
       <td class="stat"> <%= player.pv %> </td>
       <td class="stat"> <%= player.rv %> </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much Dan!